# AngularJS returning a promise causing 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code as part of my AngularJS app:

```
myApp.factory('NewContactData', function($http,$log, $q) {
 return {    
   saveContact: function(contact){
     var deferred = $q.defer();  
     ...
     ...
     return deferred.promise;     
   }, 
   getContacts: function(){
     var gcdeferred = $q.defer();  
     ...
     ...
     return gcdeferred.promise;         
   }      
 }; 
});
```

When I try to call getContacts from my app controller as follows:

```
myApp.controller('ContactsController',
        function ContactsController($scope, $location, NewContactData){


    NewContactData.getContacts().$promise.then(
            function(response){
               console.log(response);
            },
            function(status){
               console.log(status);
            }
    );
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
 at new ContactsController
```

Even though as it is shown from my code that getContacts return promise. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just `NewContactData.getContacts().then(` since you are already returning a promise

Comment: But that is really weird, as when calling saveContact I use the exact code to see if the records were saved or not and it never complained...so is this normal?

Comment: it's nonsense to call `.$promise` on the returned promise, I don't know why the other code is working for you, it shouldn't be if it is written correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NewContactData.getContacts().then(
        function(response){
           console.log(response);
        },
        function(status){
           console.log(status);
        }
);
```